# Missing Ubuntu.Components QML Module

Tags: mobile, ubuntu, qml

I installed QTCreator and Ubuntu SDK as shown [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit).
When trying to run the code sample provided [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/), QTCreator tells me it can't find the Ubuntu.Components QML Module.

**Notes**:

The build-logs says:

> file:///home/giladnaaman/Programming/Projects/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml:2 module "Ubuntu.Components" is not installed

But the directory `/opt/qt5/imports/Ubuntu/Components`
exists (and is full of files).

After adding `importPaths: [ "/opt/qt5/imports" ]` to the `qmlproject` file:

> QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.
>
> QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Type flags for 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry'[1024] don't match. Previously registered TypeFlags(0x103), now registering TypeFlags(0x3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add the **importPaths** property to the qmlproject.

Did you setup the QML Scene as your QML viewer?

1. In Qt Creator, go to **Tools > Options**…
2. Choose the **External Tools** tab, then in the pane select the **Preview (qmlviewer)** entry
3. On the **Executable:** field on the right, replace the contents with **/opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene**.
4. Optionally change the command name by double-clicking on the **Preview (qmlviewer)** entry from above. You can call it **Preview (qmlscene)**.
5. Click on OK to save the changes.

you’ll be able to view your app through the **Tools > External > Qt Quick > Preview (qmlscene)**

The Ubuntu SDK is still using the older version of Qt Creator from QT4 it will not be able to locate the Ubuntu Components, and say the components are not found. But the QML Scene used for running the QML GUI will load it and run it without any problems.